# JMeter: Failed using POST method with filters in URL and JSON in body

Tags: json, rest, api, post, jmeter

Firstly I searched the forum but couldn't find something relevant (hope I hadn't skipped anything, I'm really a beginner).

What I'm trying to do is validate a POST request (no cookies, no login credentials, only API access key)

Example URL for POST in Postman:

```
https://devenv.myapp.mainhomepage.com/api/v4/gpp-category?access_key=xyzxyz000111222333444&filter[to]=app001&filter[from]=comp9&filter[service]=mobile
```

(I wrote the access_key in URL, but in Postman works both in URL and in Headers as key: Authorization, value: xyz01234..)

Example BODY for POST in Postman:

```
{ 
   "data":{ 
      "type":"gpp-category",
      "attributes":{ 
         "standard":{ 
            "appid": "app001",
            "name": "Java",
            "developer": "Oracle",
            "discontinued": false,
            "scraper_1": "test-1"
         },
         "relationships":{ 
            "to":{ 
               "data":{ "type":"gpp-category", "id":"app001" }
            },
            "from":{ 
               "data":{ "type":"gpp-category", "id":"comp9" }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now, here's what I'm doing in JMeter:

```
1. Thread Group with HTTP Header Manager (Content-Type - application/json)
2. HTTP Request where: 
Server Name: devenv.myapp.mainhomepage.com
Path: /api/v4/gpp-category?access_key=xyzxyz000111222333444&filter[to]=app001&filter[from]=comp9&filter[service]=mobile
Body Data: the above example of body.
```

The response data in View Results Tree is:

```
{"data":[]}
```

Question: Is it from parameters or the response I received isn't decoded? Post wasn't successful, I tried GET for that id and it couldn't be found.

Comment: can you add the screenshot of how you are building the request, HTTP Sampler? and screenshots of ViewResultsTree showing Request and Response tabs of the POST request.

Comment: I've uploaded here some print-screens (had to blur/cover the data, sensitive info), but above I've written a similar example http://imgur.com/a/HefYg

Comment: In View Results Tree, as you can see, at "Request" it is shown GET method + link, even though I'm trying, hoping for a successful POST :)

Comment: I can definitely say there is a redirection for your POST request. share the screenshot of the orginal request/resposne by expanding the tree in ViewResultsTree

Comment: I think redirection is due to filters you applied in the PATH. when you are posting something to the server, why do you apply filters, which is to retrieve using a GET request

Comment: Indeed, I've expanded the result tree (composed of a http and https call for the same method and resource) it is redirected as GET. I'll keep the path simple but I'll try to find another way for the filters (are important for POST method in my api)

Comment: response data for first POST request (before it was redirected as a GET): 301 Moved Permanently